# XMPP web client

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Is there any XMPP web client except SparkWeb and JWChat?

Comment: More than one can count.... ;) I've used iChat on OSX or gChat in a browser, Pidgin, etc...

Comment: @%author%: You implied one that works via HTTP ?

Comment: Via http or https would be good!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd recommend, you can use [strophejs](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/).

The examples of the [Professional XMPP development with jQuery](http://professionalxmpp.com/) are very interesting.

Especially the [chapter 6 application](http://github.com/metajack/profxmpp/tree/master/ch06/), which is a ... chat client.

Comment: Thanks, cstar. The book seems interesting. I just bought it.

Comment: you can use stanza.io https://github.com/legastero/stanza

Answer (score 10):

There is also Jappix, which is a fresh new social-oriented XMPP web-client. You can test it here: http://www.jappix.com/ and get it on the project website (it's open source!).

Comment: The link you shared is "dead"

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Candy](http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/) - a pure JavaScript client for XMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look here ?
http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/

Comment: But among them, SparkWeb and JWChat seem to be the best. And the development of SparkWeb has been stopped.

Comment: FYI, this link is now dead.  The new link is http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/

Answer (score 1):

[JAXL IM](http://jaxl.im) is something you might want to try out... provides a convenient admin panel for configuration of chat widget, enable/disable addons and plugins for the chat widget and view chat archives...

It build using [JAXL](http://code.google.com/p/jaxl) open source library written in PHP....

Answer (score 1):

There is a GWT based client called ijab. http://code.google.com/p/ijab/