# About adding Google Talk to my website

Tags: html, google-talk

I am trying to add gTalk to my website

CODE:-

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/talk/service/badge/Show?tk=z01q6amlque8dh1ahj76nn5veh4qid1oovkbpncm3tiji81dnua3fn5541f1okhra1h29iv1q631sjlp3tgmp55gqq8mib1kr53kt4ao2t74kad5ivccd8drd32sirahntunpq7c3fp7nefv6tnacnukdnc6ef5q8bbpjsal15o5evurq7d7kqdfnn560uaoibk&amp;w=200&amp;h=60" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="60" width="200"></iframe>
```

It is displaying in browser but when some one clicks on the link if am online the page is redirected to http://support.google.com/chat/?hl=en&topic=1725163#topic=24666

I can't chat..

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be very little information floating around about this...this might be why:

> "Google is no longer supporting the chatback badge."
>
> http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chat/mTiz7cm9LTM
>    https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/chat/chatback/chat/khNawyCACHc/nrCCurEXX6YJ

Comment: Then How can i add gmail chat  to my website

Comment: I just had a dig around and came up with very little this - very strange for a Google product...it likely died quietly. Unless you use a [web based XMPP client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687612/xmpp-web-client) to interface with the [Google Talk API](https://developers.google.com/talk/talk_developers_home), you'd have to use a non-Google web chat client and/or server that worked on another service or was hosted on your web server

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It's very disappointing that the Chatback badge isn't supported.

I found OggChat to replace it. http://oggchat.com/

It designed especially for GMail and Google Talk.

You do have to pay for it, but it doesn't cost very much and it's well worth it.

It has more features than the chatback badge did.

- You can style and brand it
- You can monitor visitors by location/time spent on page
- You can invite people to chat (Manually & automatically)
- It loads asynchronously
- It saves and emails transcripts
- You can use it anywhere you can use Gmail or Google Talk

I've been using it on three websites for a year. I can't recommend it highly enough.