# Candy Chat Ejabberd user login information

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, candy

i have ejabberd installed and configured on a centos 6.5 server 
with http_bind enabled auth_method set to anonymous,internal 
using [candy-chat](http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/) as a client to connect to ejabberd on my server 
everything works just fine .. my problem comes next

i want to add more information to users logged in based on a certain log-in form ..
user supplies his username , age , country and gender

and in candy chat i want to see his nick name as follow

(country-flag as an icon)username(age) ..

so how can i modify ejabberd to work accordingly , are there are any extra modules i can add ? or plugins for candy ? i did some research of course but i couldn't come up with much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a vcard module.

1. ejabberd: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_vcard.erl
2. candy chat uses strophe.js, so extend strophe.js and try to hook it up to candy chat: https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/vcard

Comment: any ideas on how to change candy template ? i want to integrate bootstrap with it

Comment: do you know off any jabber webclient that uses bootstrap instead of candy ? i've tried several including pretty much everything in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687612/xmpp-web-client .. any ideas ?

Comment: I dont think there are any. Either you need to change candy using Bootstrap yourself or build your own client using Strophe.js.

Comment: in Candy, change the Candy.View.Template.Roster.user html to show your additional information. In Class Candy.View.Pane.Roster.update where (action === 'join'), add a call the the jabber server to get the vcard info and populate the Candy.View.Template.Roster.user item (or modify the presence announcement to get the data there).

Comment: thanks so much for you answer , but how about if i wanted to change the whole template to bootstrap ? is that applicable ?

Comment: I've never used bootstrap, so I couldn't answer that.

Comment: You can change all templates in "templates.js" (and after editing, concat all files again to candy.bundle.js/candy.min.js). Just make sure that necessary classes/ids/data attributes & variable replacements are still there.

Comment: is it possible to included vcard plugin in candy with open fire server?

Comment: According to docs it is supported: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/vcard/VCardManager.html